# Problems getting figures to show up in Matlab published PDF

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble publishing my m-files to PDF format in the R2012a version of Matlab. I'm able to publish to html format but when I try to publish to PDF format, any figures (plots) I have in my script pop up but then close after a while without the PDF file itself getting published.

I'm running in a Linux environment and using an Intel machine. Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the command you are using to publish to .pdf?

Comment: I'm using the toolbar print button...I know, not very 1337. Do you recommend that I use a publish command from the command line and if so what command?

Comment: Have you watched this video? http://www.mathworks.com/support/2009b/matlab/7.9/demos/new-matlab-publishing-features-in-r2009b.html

Comment: That's what I was trying to do (what was demonstrated in the video). When I change the output format to pdf and click 'Publish', the plots all pop up but the pdf file itself never gets made.

Comment: as an option you may have a better luck in publishing in word format and then convert your word file to pdf.

Comment: Since html works, why not take that output and convert to pdf... I am not near a computer where I can test things right now, sorry.